# Unexpected response code 500 for http://10.0.2.2:8000/req

Tags: java, php, laravel

I want to send `JsonObjectRequest` to `Laravel`. But I am facing this problem:

> E/Volley: [239] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code
>   500 for http://10.0.2.2:8000/req

I have searched on the internet but I could not find an answer to this problem.

My Java code:

```
public void loginUser(String email, String password, final OnLoginResponse onLoginResponse){
        JSONObject requestJsonObject=new JSONObject();
        try {
            requestJsonObject.put("email",email);
            requestJsonObject.put("password",password);


            JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://10.0.2.2:8000/req",requestJsonObject , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "loginUser: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

My Laravel code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ReqDemoController extends Controller
{
     public function getData(Request $request){
        $data =  $request->json()->all(); 
        $email = $data->input('email');
        $pass = $data->input('password');
        DB::table('login')->insert([
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $pass
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This page is generally unreachable. Can you check if this ip is actually working and double check your URL?

Comment: try to run the request  http://10.0.2.2:8000/req in browser to check whether you are able to recieve response

Comment: in emulator this page with google chrome is open with this ip (http://10.0.2.2:8000/req) but localhost:8000 and http://192.168.1.4/ can't running.

Comment: Do you have control over the requested server? Then you should look in that server's error log to see what caused that error 500

Comment: in my pc this page : 10.0.2.2:8000/req does not run but in emulator runing without problem.

Comment: this is Laravel logs::::[2019-03-01 11:09:43] local.ERROR: Call to a member function input() on array {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function input() on array at /home/ramtin/Desktop/QaServer/app/Http/Controllers/ReqDemoController.php:11)

Comment: So, what have you tried to solve that error? What **exactly** does `$data` contain?

Comment: data is contain email and password that save to database PhpMyAdmin , this is a one test for save data with laravel for me .

Comment: perhaps your emulator starts the script in 127.0.0.1:8000, you  can't access it with 10.0.2.2

Comment: in emulator 127.0.0.1:8000 does not run.but 10.0.2.2:8000 runing in browser without problem .